# Unable to install android application in my mobile

Tags: android

I am an Android Application Developer. Just a few days ago, i added repositories to my eclipse juno for creating an android app development environment inside my eclipse. During my first app being build and deployed to the android environment, i got a problem with the .apk file as  when it was exported to my android phone, the app name changed to alokappnull from alokapp(name given by me to the app) and the app didn't install. Suggest proper solution.

Comment: What messages did the developer console show you when you first ran the application? Did the new app run correctly? Are you talking about the app name, the abbreviated name (when shown on homescreen), the actual package name, or the name of the apk (which can be different as well without affecting the app name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have to delete your older app and then try installing the new app again. The two app have different signatures if you changed from debug to release version.

Answer (score 0):

What's the origin of the apk, does it contain an application developed by you?
Make sure you enabled in your device settings the use of applications from unknown sources.